# ZIP related exception after saving WordprocessingDocument

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to replace text in a `docx` document based on this sample, with some modifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part#sample-code

However, the saved document is not valid anymore. Word is able to correct the file, but there is a `Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.` exception is thrown at `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadCentralDirectory()` when trying to open the created file again with `WordprocessingDocument`.

My code looks like this:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await fs.CopyToAsync(ms);
    
    using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
    {
        string docText;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        
        /*Regex regexText = new Regex("text to replace");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "new text");*/

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {       
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
    
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(target, ms.GetBuffer());
}

using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(target, true))
{
    
}
```

The issue is not repated to the replace itself. Even **reading** the `MainDocumentPart` in any way causes this exception to be thrown.

Why the streams? I want to create and modify a document from template and save it afterwards to a stream. But I haven't found any `CreateFromTemplate` overload neither a `Save`/`SaveAs` overload that accepts a stream.

Comment: You never rewind your `MemoryStream` after copying into it. So the `WordProcessingDocument.Open` call is being given a stream with no bytes left to read. `ms.Position = 0`

Comment: Also that `await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(target, ms.GetBuffer())` will be wring garbage to the end of the file. `GetBuffer()` returns the underlying buffer, which will be larger than the number of bytes written to it. If you use the buffer returned by `GetBuffer()`, you **must** limit how many bytes are read from it, based on `ms.Position`. Either use `ToArray()` and suck up the cost of the intermediate allocation, or open a `FileStream` and `ms.CopyTo(fs)`

Comment: @canton7 It was there originally. Makes no difference.

Comment: @canton7 The garbage was the cause. Thank you!

Comment: Bleh, *writing, and you'll need to look at `ms.Length` to see how many bytes to write of course, not `ms.Position`. Glad that fixed your problem!